# Where do you check to if a hotfix from Microsoft have been applied to any service packs?

Tags: hotfix

I have a interest in a [reported bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941132/en-us) which Microsoft have made available a hotfix for. When looking on the site, I'm not able to figure out if this fix is included in a service pack or not. Do anyone know where I can find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention your product but:

List of fixes in Service Pack 1 for XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324720

List of fixes in Service Pack 2 for XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811113

List of fixes in Service Pack 3 for XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946480

List of fixes in Service Pack 1 for Vista: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749061.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For security-related patches, try MBSA: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184924.aspx

Also try running a WMI query against installed hotfixes. I believe that Service Packs register bundled hotfixes.